# Replace image filename in url using regular expression

Tags: .htaccess

I have many images hosted with the similar urls and want to replace image names using .htaccess/regex in URL from:

```
https://wwww.mydomain.com/img/ID_1234_bla_bla_bla.jpg
```

to:

```
https://wwww.mydomain.com/img/id1234.jpg
```

where (ID_1234) randge is 1-9999

i.e.
"ID">"id" (to lowercase)
"slash"  out
number range 1-9999

No idea how to do that

Comment: Please do share your htaccess tried rule file in your question(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Comment: I have no idea sorry

Comment: You could go through https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/getting-started.html link and try something then post that efforts in your question(there is nothing wrong or right here), because on Stack overflow its highly encouraged to post efforts, else questions will be closed, thank you.

Comment: no thanks........... every time I go there is a full mess

Comment: Ok, try with this https://www.vanstechelman.eu/content/automatically-redirect-non-existing-pages-home-page-apache one once, to get a start and then you could edit your question with efforts, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\/)ID_(\d\d\d\d)_[^\.\s]*(.*)$ $1id$2$3
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/N6irNe/1/)